# How to check if the Oauth-2.0 migration is done?

Tags: facebook, verification

I am a facebook developer have a site which registers using fbconnect register feature/button. We use following SDK:FeatureLoader.js.php/en_US for the same.

Now to migrate to Aouth-2.0 I have added the "oauth:true" to FB.init function on my page  and also enabled the Oauth radio button on my facebook app settings.

But can some body help me out to how I can verify that my app is now Oauth-2.0 enabled as I can register without "oauth:true" as well.No effect of adding and removing it?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you have the sandbox settings enabled. If so, oauth (true or false) will function. Disable the Sandbox Mode and look if it still works.